# Codefresh allure pytest

Tags: allure, codefresh

I am trying to use allure for code fresh. We are using pytest to generate reports. After I clone the repo, in documentation it is mentioned to running_tests:
image: node
title: Running Unit tests
commands:
- npm test
- cp -r -f ./allure-results $CF_VOLUME_PATH/allure-results

I want to use pytest. I am new to code fresh. I am trying to understand after I clone the repo how do I reflect the pytest allure report there and send it to code fresh volume. How to run pytest to the Github repo I cloned. Should I provide working directory?. In the above code they are not using any git clone or working directory. If I use docker file is there a way to send reports to code fresh volume. Thanks.